# How can I display a child component with data from parent component after clicking update method that sends data and also return data

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I am working with two components (Angular 15) child & parent, so the first component (parent) has a form in a table with data coming from an API, users have to select an item and click update, on the same update method I am calling another method that returns data to be displayed on the child component.

I am expecting the second component to load the table with data after clicking update.

The issue here is that the data is not loaded in the table immediately, I wrapped the child component with

```
<ng-content *ngIf= "updateClicked === true" >
<child component [data]=data> <child component>
<ng-content >
```

I have tried change detection but maybe I am using it incorrectly.

Comment: I would keep your data an observable and use the async pipe like this:

`<child-component *ngIf="data$ | async as data" [data]="data"></child-component>`